# How to read multiple xml files from different folder in Java

Tags: java, xml, csv

I have to access multiple xml files located in a single parent folder, But inside that parent folder, there are multiple sub folder and inside those sub folders there are sometimes more sub folder and then the xml files. I have written a code to read a single xml file and the output the xml data to a csv. Below is my code.
Please review the code and provide any relevant solution.

```
public class XMLReader_Rar{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{

        File inputfile = new File("C:/Users/Vishvesh Savant/Desktop/Mirriad/Test/data4/subdir4/468736483.xml");


        File filePath = new File ("C:/Users/Vishvesh Savant/Desktop/Mirriad/Test/data4/subdir4/new.csv");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dbuilder = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc =  dbuilder.parse(inputfile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath);

        try{
            for(int i=0; i<list.getLength();i++){

                Node node = list.item(i);

                if(node.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                    Element element = (Element) node;

                    fileWriter.append(element.getAttribute("uid"));
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("actor").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("director").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("format").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("bitrate").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("fps").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("aspect").item(0).getTextContent() );
                    fileWriter.append(",");
                    fileWriter.append( element.getElementsByTagName("width").item(0).getTextContent() );

                    fileWriter.flush();
                    fileWriter.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Files.walk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-). It returns a stream of path (all - folder and files) which you should filter (by type, extention, name and etc.)

```
String rootPath = "D:\\tmp";
Files.walk(Paths.get(rootPath)).filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(p -> {
    File file = new File(p.toUri());
    //logic with file
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
});
```

Comment: Can you please use that in the above code which I have provided. if possible

Comment: That comment comes 9 minutes after the answer was posted. You really need to be prepared to put in more than 9 minutes' effort to understand and apply the answer, before asking for further help. This isn't a free coding service.

Comment: @michal Kay With due respect I had tried similar things which I had found on this same forum before posting my question which did not seem to work, Even before that I tried many more things which did not seem to work before even posting. I post questions on this forum only when I have done enough of research and trial and error work on my code.

Comment: Where do you want to locate csv files? Is each next to its source xml-file, or are all csv files in common folder?

Comment: basically I want to retrieve data from the folders that have the xml file and then add that retrieved data to a single csv file (which can be in any location).

The folder structure of my xml files is like this for example.
Parent folder
- Sub Folder 1
----Sub folder 3
-------xml file

- Sub Folder 2
----xml file